# Summing Records within a Moving Date Range, Date Distances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have complex calculation requirement for a user logging system. I need to locate the most frequently active users based on their number of logins within a 180 day window. Once two login dates are 181 days apart, they do not count towards a total but could count towards a total when grouped with other dates.

For example here is Jim's login history:

```
Jim 2018-01-01
Jim 2018-04-01
Jim 2018-05-01
Jim 2018-06-01
Jim 2018-07-01
Jim 2018-08-01
Jim 2018-09-01
Jim 2018-12-01
```

Using 6 months, instead of 180 days, for simplicity, and only looking 6 months in one direction, Jim had the following totals:

```
Logins: 5 (2018-01-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 6 (2018-04-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 5 (2018-05-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 5 (2018-06-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 4 (2018-07-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 3 (2018-08-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 2 (2018-09-01 + 6 months)
Logins: 1 (2018-12-01 + 6 months)
```

So my system would report back 6 because it only wants the maximum total.

Other than brute force calculation, I'm lost on how to construct this system. Yes I can denormalize data to any degree, speed is most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table(name char(3), dt date);
insert into @tbl values
('Jim', '2018-01-01'),
('Jim', '2018-04-01'),
('Jim', '2018-05-01'),
('Jim', '2018-06-01'),
('Jim', '2018-07-01'),
('Jim', '2018-08-01'),
('Jim', '2018-09-01'),
('Jim', '2018-12-01');

;with cte as (
    select name, dt, DATEADD(day, 181, dt) upperDt from @tbl
), cte2 as (
    select name,
           (select COUNT(*) from cte where dt between c.dt and c.upperDt and name = c.name) cnt
    from cte c
)

select name, MAX(cnt) [max] 
from cte2 
group by name
```

Comment: @Moonstone Just in case, I updated my question to fit more to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One basic solution uses a `join`:

```
select l.*
from (select l.name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from logins l join
           logins l2
           on l.name = l2.name and
              l2.date >= l.date and l2.date < dateadd(day, 181, l.date)
      group by l.name
     ) l
where seqnum = 1;
```

This might have acceptable performance with an index on `logins(name, date)`.

Comment: Testing this out with a temp table.
`Column '@logins.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to Calculate the EndDate Window and [CROSS APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) to calculate the total number of logins

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (UserName NVARCHAR(10), LoginDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @t
(UserName,LoginDate) VALUES
('Jim','2018-01-01'),
('Jim','2018-04-01'),
('Jim','2018-05-01'),
('Jim','2018-06-01'),
('Jim','2018-07-01'),
('Jim','2018-08-01'),
('Jim','2018-09-01'),
('Jim','2018-12-01')

; WITH CteDateRange
AS(
    SELECT
         T.UserName
        ,T.LoginDate 
        --,EndDateRange = DATEADD(DAY, 181, LoginDate)
        ,EndDateRange = DATEADD(MONTH, 6, LoginDate)
    FROM @t T
)
SELECT
     DR.UserName
    ,DR.LoginDate
    ,DR.EndDateRange
    ,T.Total
FROM CteDateRange DR
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT  Total = COUNT(D.LoginDate) 
                FROM    CteDateRange D 
                WHERE   D.LoginDate >= DR.LoginDate 
                AND     D.LoginDate <= DR.EndDateRange 
                AND     D.UserName = DR.UserName
            ) T
```

Output

```
UserName    LoginDate               EndDateRange            Total
Jim         2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 5
Jim         2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 6
Jim         2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 2018-11-01 00:00:00.000 5
Jim         2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 5
Jim         2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 4
Jim         2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 3
Jim         2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2
Jim         2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: Oh, this is similar to Michal's answer.